# How to get a list of recent files -view for Caret?

Tags: text-editors, chromebook, caret

I would like to get TextMate's feature to Caret that you press CMD-Shift-T and you get a list of recent files in your directory where you can easily open files there.

Caret is so advanced so I think something similar must exist there.

How can you review files in the directory of the current file in Caret?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to File -> View Current Files to show a list of loaded files.

For a full list of Caret commands, you can check out the wiki from the writer of Caret, Thomas Wilburn:

https://github.com/thomaswilburn/Caret/wiki/Commands

EDIT: irrelevant links, see comment below.

Comment: Sorry. The second link is not relevant. It is about different software in brain mapping. The third link is about Caret in OSX/Linux and Windows. All those keybinding do not work in Chromebook, for instarce CTRL-/ to toggle a comment does not work in Chromebook. Here a particular thread just about toggling the comment in Chromebook's Caret http://superuser.com/q/981510/2005

Comment: There is no option "File > View Current Files" to show current files at the moment in Caret. How did you get this option?