# Why CTRL-/ not Toggle comment in tex file of Caret?

Tags: chromebook, caret

I have a tex file where I see the syntax correctly highlighted. 
However, I would like to use the keybinding, toggle comment, but CTRL-/ is not working as described in the menu Edit.

How can you toggle comment in a tex file of Caret?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the [Ace Editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) code used by [Caret](https://github.com/thomaswilburn/Caret). While waiting for the source to be patched, you can correct it yourself:

1. Insert `this.lineCommentStart = "%";` at line 139 of `/js/ace/mode-tex.js` in Caret's source code.
2. Then reload Caret as an unpackaged extension.

Update: the bug has been fixed for the next build. The fix won't be seen in Caret until its author updates however.

Comment: When is the next build coming out?